# htaccess rewrite only if request uri is empty

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My current .htaccess is as follow:

```
##FOR DUAL LEVEL TIER SUBDOMAIN
#SUBDOMAIN REWRITE for COUNTRY.CATEGORY.uqloo.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydomain.com$ [NC] # Presuming you don't want to do www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.mydomain\.com [NC] # Catch subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sub1=%1&sub2=%2 [QSA,L]

##FOR SINGLE LEVEL TIER SUBDOMAIN
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydomain.com$ [NC] # Presuming you don't want to do www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com [NC] # Catch subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ [NC] # Don't rewrite if we already have
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sub1=%1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm trying to do single and dual level subdomain redirect only while keeping all my other rewrites for the URI parts relevant. I want to keep the parameters for subdomain relevant as well for the URI rewrites.

An example will be the following rule keeps getting redirected back to **`index.php`** when it should go to **`pages/details.php`** with parameters sub1 and sub2 available if the subdomain is present.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)?/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$

pages/details.php?adid=$1&alias=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# pages URL handlers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ pages/details.php?sub1=%1&adid=$1&alias=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ pages/details.php?sub1=%1&sub2=%2&adid=$1&alias=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# subdomain rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?sub1=%1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?sub1=%1&sub2=%2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: okay now it works. But is it possible that my rewrite rules under #pages URL will also inherit the parameters of sub1?

Comment: Awesome. Last Question. say if i have a 2 tiered domain? eg: http://[country].[category].mydomain.com . How would it look like?

Comment: I'm looking for something like RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sub1=%1&sub2=%2 [QSA,L]; This will produce: 2 $_GET results

Comment: we do the filtering within the pages.

Comment: ok check updated rules. Just a suggestion for future, It is always better to specify all the requirements upfront in the question.

Comment: okay. I want to keep it simple for a start. I'll update the post.